# How to clean up a groovy script output?

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy

I am using a groovy script to select some existing Jenkins jobs. but the result is ugly.  see this [image]

What I need is only between [].
My script is below:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
    job.name =~ /^JM*/
}

matchedJobs.each { job ->
    println job.name
    //job.delete()
}
```

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Seee [this demo](https://ideone.com/Sbzd3f).

Comment: To use it inside `findAll`, you may try `job.name =~ /(?<=\[)[^\]\[]+(?=])/`

Comment: but i need some jobs which only starts with a specific word.

Comment: Ok, `job.name =~ /(?<=\[)LM[^\]\[]*(?=])/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you got on the screen the return value of this script

if there is no `return` operator then script returns the value from your last operator.

the last operator in your case:

```
matchedJobs.each { job ->
    println job.name
    //job.delete()
}
```

the function each{...} returns the subject (matchedJobs in your case)

to solve problem try this:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
    job.name =~ /^JM*/
}

return matchedJobs.collect{ job -> job.name }
```